# Align data in one column with another row, based on the last time some condition was true

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I’m trying to parse millions of lines of log files that suffer from an unfortunate deficiency. Data relating to a single event can be split across log entries but there is no direct link with which to realign the data across several rows into a single row; instead I have to infer the relationship.

Brief background:

1. There are 4 objects that I care about that will be modified many times
2. There is a threadpool of 8 threads that will collect one of those things at random and begin processing it. This event is identified by `thing_n`, `A`, `B`, and `C` all having non-null values and I can get the thread number from this logged event too.
3. Somewhere later in the log, there will be a log entry on how many iterations that thread carried out. This event will contain no other information (i.e. it will not report `thing_n` that it operated on)
4. `thread_num`/`thing_n` pairings will change constantly
5. Any number of threads can log any number of events between point 2 and 3, so you cannot simply `.shift()` the `Iterations` column to realign data into a single row.

Somehow I need to realign the Iterations column with the previous (and only the previous) row in which `thing_I_care_about`, `A`, `B`, `C` are not null, and the `thread_num` matches. There are timestamps (not in my MCVE), and all events are sorted in ascending order if that helps.

Example input:

```
   thing_I_care_about  thread_num    A    B    C      Iterations
0  thing_1             2             X    X    X      NaN
1  NaN                 2             X    X    NaN    NaN
2  thing_2             3             NaN  X    X      NaN
3  NaN                 2             NaN  NaN  NaN    110.0
4  thing_3             7             X    X    X      NaN
5  thing_4             5             X    X    NaN    NaN
6  NaN                 7             NaN  NaN  NaN    150.0
```

Example output:

```
   thing_I_care_about  thread_num    A    B    C      Realigned Iterations
0  thing_1             2             X    X    X      110.0
1  NaN                 2             X    X    NaN    NaN
2  thing_2             3             NaN  X    X      NaN
3  NaN                 2             NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN
4  thing_3             7             X    X    X      150.0
5  thing_4             5             X    X    NaN    NaN
6  NaN                 7             NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

I can manage a pure python approach (bottom), but this analysis will be done repeatedly on demand and have to process hundreds of millions of such events. Conceptually, the only way I can think of doing this in Pandas is:

1. `groupby()` `thread_num` and sort each group by their timestamp
2. Try somehow to get a DF for each thread with alternating `notnull([thing_n, A, B, C, thread_num])` and `notnull([thread_num, Iterations])` rows so that I could `shift(-1)` them to realign the data
3. Somehow tie this back to the original DataFrame

However, I cannot seem to make progress with this approach. Is there any smart way of doing this, or am I stuck processing this part in Python?

Pure python approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [['thing_I_care_about', 'thread_num', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Iterations'], ['thing_1', 2, 'X', 'X', 'X', np.nan], [np.nan, 2, 'X', 'X', np.nan, np.nan], ['thing_2', 3, np.nan, 'X', 'X', np.nan], [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 110], ['thing_3', 7, 'X', 'X', 'X', np.nan], ['thing_4', 5, 'X', 'X', np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 150]]

data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data[1:], columns=raw_data[0])
print "Input format"
print data

header_dict = {item: x for x, item in enumerate(data.columns)}

# Take data out of DF to become nested list
data_list = data.as_matrix()

# Track the row in which a thread starts its process
active_threads = {} 

# Create a list to become to re-aligned column in the DF at the end for num iterations
realigned_data = [np.nan for x in xrange(len(data_list))]

for x, entry in enumerate(data_list):
    thread_num = int(entry[header_dict['thread_num']])

    if all([pd.notnull(entry[header_dict['thing_I_care_about']]),
           pd.notnull(entry[header_dict['A']]),
           pd.notnull(entry[header_dict['B']]),
           pd.notnull(entry[header_dict['C']])]):
        active_threads[thread_num] = x

    elif pd.notnull(entry[header_dict['Iterations']]) and entry[header_dict['thread_num']] in active_threads:
        realigned_data[active_threads[thread_num]] = entry[header_dict['Iterations']]

data['realigned_iterations'] = realigned_data
print "Output format"
print data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, I think you can do it this way.  Create two masking one representing the rows where the current Iteration value is now.  And, the second mask puts True on the first record where you want the Iteration value to move too.  Then group on the first mask with cumsum and put that current value on all records, then use the second mask with where.

```
mask=(df['thing_I_care_about'].isnull() &
      df['A'].isnull() &
      df['B'].isnull() &
      df['C'].isnull())

fmask  = (df['thing_I_care_about'].notnull() &
      df['A'].notnull() &
      df['B'].notnull() &
      df['C'].notnull())

df.assign(Iterations=df.groupby(mask[::-1].cumsum())['Iterations'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).where(fmask))
```

Output:

```
  thing_I_care_about  thread_num    A    B    C  Iterations
0            thing_1           2    X    X    X       110.0
1                NaN           2    X    X  NaN         NaN
2            thing_2           3  NaN    X    X         NaN
3                NaN           2  NaN  NaN  NaN         NaN
4            thing_3           7    X    X    X       150.0
5            thing_4           5    X    X  NaN         NaN
6                NaN           7  NaN  NaN  NaN         NaN
```

Comment: This looks seriously cool. It's going to take me a while to be able to verify this on my full dataset and also get my head around the last line. But certainly it looks like it does what I need; I hope my example data was sufficient to test this - will it cope with `thread_num == 2` appearing a second time? EDIT: Thread 2 (for example) must report both the "pickup" of the `thing_I_care_about` and the number of iterations it did on that, before it is free to go again. That's the only pattern.

Comment: @roganjosh All this really cares about is the four column all null and  all four columns that are not null.  Anything between those rows really don't matter.  Let me know know and explain that last statement.

Comment: I edited my last comment to make it clearer btw. It might be tomorrow before I can test this now as I'm struggling to run my query to get the data from home. I will report back ASAP.