# Conditional Row shift in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to shift a row based on whether or not another column is not null. There's inconsistent spacing in the Description column so I can't do a .shift()

Here's the original data

```
Permit Number    A      Description
1234            NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    foo
3456            NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    bar
```

And this is what I want my result to be

```
Permit Number    A      Description
1234            NaN    foo
NaN             NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    NaN
3456            NaN    bar
NaN             NaN    NaN
```

Here's the code that I used from [Align data in one column with another row, based on the last time some condition was true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381840/align-data-in-one-column-with-another-row-based-on-the-last-time-some-condition)

```
mask = df['Description'].notnull()
fmask = (df['Permit Number'].notnull() & df['Description'].isnull())
df.assign(Description=df.groupby(mask[::-1].cumsum())['Description'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).where(fmask))
```

However when I run it, no errors and no changes in the dataframe.

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: I am looking to shift the column titled Description based on whether the Permit Number column is null or not. If the Permit Number column is not null, take the non null field in Description and shift it so it is in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for anyone who sees this that might have a string in their column, this solutions works too

```
mask = df['Description'].notnull()
fmask = (df['Permit Number'].notnull() & df['Description'].isnull())
df = df.assign(Description=df.groupby(mask[::-1].cumsum())['Description'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).where(fmask))
```

I had a simple error of not "writing" the newly grouped dataframe back to df

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the NaN rows, you can go like following. I can't test it, but let me know if there's any typo.

this is the original.

```
Permit Number    A      Description
1234            NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    foo
3456            NaN    NaN
NaN             NaN    bar
```

I try to achieve this one first :

```
df['Permit Number'] = df['Permit Number'].ffill()
Permit Number    A      Description
1234            NaN    NaN
1234            NaN    NaN
1234            NaN    foo
3456            NaN    NaN
3456            NaN    bar
```

then you have the result as you ask.

```
df.groupby(['Permit Number','A'])['Description'].max().reset_index()
Permit Number    A      Description
1234            NaN    foo
3456            NaN    bar
```